# Where to load contract to prevent undefined methods when calling contract?

Tags: javascript, next.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I am trying to run a method from my smart contract located on the ropsten test network but am running into the following error in my getBalance() function:

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'methods')

```
  46 |     async function getBalance() {
> 47 |       const tempBal = await window.contract.methods.balanceOf(account.data).call()
     |                                            ^
  48 |       setBalance(tempBal)
  49 |     }
```

Connecting my contract:

```
export default function ConnectContract() {
    

    async function loadWeb3() {
        if (window.ethereum) {
          window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
          window.ethereum.enable()
        }
      }
  
      async function loadContract() {
        const tempContract = await new window.web3.eth.Contract(ABI, ContractAddress)
        return tempContract
      }
  
      async function load() {
        await loadWeb3();
        window.contract = await loadContract();
      }

      load();

}
```

Currently the functions are being called like so:

```
 export default function Page() {
    ConnectContract();
    getBalance();
 }
```

Another way I previous called it that did not result in the undefined error was by using an onClick function inside a button to getBalance:

```
 <div><button onClick={() => getBalance}>Get Balance</button></div>
```

I know calling them like this is causing the getBalance function method to be called before the contract is connected to the website but with the current code, it works after 1-page refresh. But I have not been able to find a solution to make the contract be loaded so the method is defined by the time getBalance is called.

I have tried doing onLoad function and window.load() functions with no success. I have also tried calling my ConnectContract function in the _app.js to load it when the website is launched but that had no success as well.

Comment: Try to remove the methods from the command it should be just `await window.contract.balanceOf(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the `loadWeb3` function inside `useEffect` hook. `useEffect` is used to prepare the state for the component when it is mounted. to keep track of the state, use `useState` hook

```
const [web3,setWeb3]=useState('')
const [contract,setContract]=useState('')

async function loadWeb3() {
        if (window.ethereum) {
          window.ethereum.enable()
          setWeb3(new Web3(window.ethereum))         
        }
      }

// [] array means we want this useEffect code run only when the compoenent rerenders
// Since loadWeb3 is async function, call it inside try/catch block
useEffect(()=>{loadWeb3()},[])
```

Next we you need to prepare contract same way.

```
async function loadContract() {
        const tempContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, ContractAddress)
        setContract(tempContract)
      }
```

You also need to call this in `useEffect` but this time its dependencies are different. Because in order to get the contract, we are relying on `web3`

```
// Since loadContract is async function, call it inside try/catch block
useEffect(()=>{loadContract},[web3])
```

when component renders, first useEffect will run and set the `web3`. Since web3 is changed, component will rerender again this useEffect will run. So when your component is mounted, you will have `web3` and `contract` set so you can use those.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in this code right here:

```
  46 |     async function getBalance() {
> 47 |       const tempBal = await window.contract.methods.balanceOf(account.data).call()
     |                                            ^
  48 |       setBalance(tempBal)
  49 |     }
```

My guess is that the window.contract either doesn't exist or isn't getting loaded before this gets called. Perhaps it is either getting called in a serverside place where the window doesn't exist or try wrapping it in an if function so that it checks to make sure it exists before calling it